# Include default app in Win 10 'Open with...'?

Tags: windows-10

I think my question is best presented visually:

[image]

I should have added that no attempt I've made so far to add 'GPS Utilty' to the list has succeeded, presumably because it's the 'associated' program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The executable doesn't have a name or description. This is preventing it from be listed in the Open with sub menu. See if tis REG fix helps.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\gpsu528.exe]
"ApplicationCompany"="A S Murphy"
"FriendlyAppName"="GPS Utility"
```

Now, here it is.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Asked in three forums and a newsgroup and yours is the only solution!

Answer (score 3):

There is an Default Programs setting in the Control Panel > Default Programs.  There you can choose the default program (the one that automatically opens on a double click) and also file type associations (i.e. make your program associated with the given file type, being offered for Open With).

See this [article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/quickly-fix-windows-file-type-associations/) for details.